# what is the missing code for this.?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.des;

import com.example.des.Question1;
import com.example.des.R;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Question1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    CheckBox q1;
    CheckBox q2;
    CheckBox q3;
    CheckBox q4;
    Button btndone;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);


        q1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q1a);
        q2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q2a);
        q3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q3a);
        q4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q4a);

        btndone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
        btndone.setOnClickListener(this);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (q1.isChecked() && q2.isChecked()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show();         
        }

        if (q3.isChecked() && q4.isChecked()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.negative).show();         
        }

    }
}
```

if q1 and q2 is check then the result must be positive then if q3 and q4 then it must be negative..but when i check q1,q2 and q3..it also goes positive and it should not give a result..when it is not only q1 and q2 are checked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned the problem if 1, 2, and 3 are checked, but I'll assume it would also be a problem if 2, 3, and 4 are checked, or something like that. You would need to change both if statements.

```
// if 1 and 2 are checked, but 3 and 4 aren't
if (q1.isChecked() && q2.isChecked() && !q3.isChecked() && !q4.isChecked()) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show();         
}

// otherwise, if 3 and 4 are checked, but 1 and 2 aren't
else if (q3.isChecked() && q4.isChecked() && !q1.isChecked() && !q2.isChecked()){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.negative).show();         
}
```

You can also use an `else if` rather than an `if` for the second condition (they both can't happen).

Comment: actually..it is an expert system..so i will use many of that conditions..maybe up to q9..and its about 800+combinations

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully I understood you right:

```
if (q1.isChecked() && q2.isChecked() && !q3.isChecked() && !q4.isChecked()) {
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show();         
}
```

Will only work if `q1` and `q2` are checked and the other two are not.